# error: expected identifier or '(' before 'while'

Tags: c

Recbio un error al ejecutar el siguiente codigo, donde se encuentra el error?

```
int I= 0;
int J= 0;
int M[10][10];
 while (I<10) {
     J= 1;
     while (J<10) {
        if (((M[I][J] % 2)==1) and (M[I][J]= M[I][J] * 2))
            J= J+2;

     }
     I= I+1;
  }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error da? ¿Cuál es tu hipótesis? No queremos ser unos meros debuggers de tu código ;-)

Comment: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'while' tal vez es culpa de la declaracion del array?

Comment: por favor, dale a [edit] para incluir esta importante información en la pregunta. En los comentarios es más difícil entendernos

Comment: @fedorqui actualizado gracias

Comment: El único error que veo aquí es que hay un identificador `and` entre dos operaciones relacionales. `and` no es un operador de C _(De hecho ese fue el error que me arrojó)_, si quieres hacer la conjunción lógica utiliza `&&`.

Comment: Estoy con @NaCl, tienes un error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (((M[I][J] % 2)==1) and (M[I][J]= M[I][J] * 2))
```

En C, no existe la palabra reservada **`and`**.

Los operadores lógicos del lenguaje son:

- `&&` -> *and* lógico.
- `||` -> *or* lógico.
- `!` -> *not* lógico.

Cambia tu código por

```
if (((M[I][J] % 2)==1) && (M[I][J]= M[I][J] * 2))
```